# Why are Hundreds of json files in the node_modules/.cache/babel-loader folder in a react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, babel-loader

Set up a react app with create-react-app.
Everything works fine.
Problem:
On vscode, the git tab is always showing hundreds of json files modification and creation on the folder `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader`. 
This did not happen on my previous projects.

I've tried reinstalling babel with no results.
Deleting the files does nothing.

files in the folder look as fallows: `0aab1329ff345c34fe844d530b69ce5d.json`

Comment: that is how babel-loader's cache mechanism is implemented.  FYI, it is recommended that the `node_modules` directory in your project be added to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only see created files, then you should just add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` file. If you see modified files, then you have already committed these to source control. You should remove them with `git rm` and still add `node_modules` to `.gitignore`.